# iOS Streaming Media - Media File Segmenter

Tags: ios, streaming, m3u8

Just wondering if anyone knows of a script or program that does this automatically and / or as a batch process for say 50 mp4 videos. I'm talking about the process of segmenting a video using the CLI mediafilesegmenter command for streaming from Amazon S3 as a m3u8 and then creating a variant playlist file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh -x
#set variables for naming conventions

path="$1"

if [[ -d $path ]]; then

    cd "$path"

    for file in *{.mov,.mp4}

    do

        if [[ -a $file ]]; then

            file_name="$file"
            file_no_extension=${file_name%.*}
            file_base_name=$(basename "$file_no_extension")
            file_output_dir="$file_no_extension/high"
            file_plist="$file_no_extension.plist"


            #Make directories per video
            mkdir "$file_no_extension"
            mkdir "$file_output_dir"

            #Segment Video
            mediafilesegmenter -t 5 -I "$file_name" -f "$file_output_dir"

            #Move plist file
            mv "$file_plist" "$file_output_dir/$file_base_name.plist"

            #Change directories
            cd "$file_no_extension"

            #Generate Playlist
            variantplaylistcreator "high/prog_index.m3u8" "high/$file_base_name.plist"

            cd ".."
        fi

    done

elif [[ -f $path ]]; then

    file=$1
    file_name="$file"
    file_no_extension=${file_name%.*}
    file_base_name=$(basename "$file_no_extension")
    file_output_dir="$file_no_extension/high"
    file_plist="$file_no_extension.plist"


    #Make directories per video
    mkdir "$file_no_extension"
    mkdir "$file_output_dir"

    #Segment Video
    mediafilesegmenter -t 5 -I "$file_name" -f "$file_output_dir"

    #Move plist file
    mv "$file_plist" "$file_output_dir/$file_base_name.plist"

    #Change directories
    cd "$file_no_extension"

    #Generate Playlist
    variantplaylistcreator "high/prog_index.m3u8" "high/$file_base_name.plist"

    cd ".."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an app that does this exactly here...

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/one-click-m3u8/id607270902?mt=12